# How to wrap a text and image in a same line - Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to add 64x64 image right align image with right align text which keeps the same alignment whether image section is over (as in the image 1). This is the code I used.

```
<img class="wp-image-2896 size-full alignright" style="float: right;" src="source" />
<div class="txt-head" style="text-align: right;">Cut The Costs</div>

<p style="text-align: right;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
```

Css

```
.txt-head{
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:700;
}

.mobs-txt-head-one{
   font-size:18px;
    font-weight:700;
}
```

But end result is like this

[My Expecting result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q79f6.png)
[My actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evuAQ.png)
Kindly me with this.

Thank You!!

Comment: try display:flex concept

Comment: Combine title and text in one div and image as other. Then simply use width proportion or just use flex display for better results

Comment: Hi @Manjunath it worked. Thank you very much